# How to plot multiple values (same unit) on Y axis using plotly express in Streamlit?

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I created **st.selectbox/multiselect** feature which I can choose my X axis and Y axis in the Streamlit. I only choose one column for the X axis however I want to have this option to choose multiple values and able to plot them on Y axis (with the same unit).
I get error that "All arguments must have the same size". Here is a piece of

**code:**

```
all_columns_names = df.columns.tolist()

col_x = st.selectbox('Which Feature on X axis?', all_columns_names)

col_y = st.multiselect('Which Feature on Y axis?', all_columns_names)

fig = px.line(df, x =col_x,y=col_y)

st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways do that. With the same unit on Y axis:

`st.line_chart(df.set_index(col_x)[col_y])`

With different unit on Y axis, which I prefer this one and makes more sense:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=len(col_y), cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.03)

for i in range(len(col_y)):

    fig.add_trace(go.Line(x = df[col_x], y = df[col_y[i]],name=col_y[i]),row=len(col_y)-i, col=1)

st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies on the following line:

```
fig = px.line(df, x=col_x, y=col_y)
```

In the code sample you provided `st.selectbox` returns a column, and `st.multiselect` returns an array of columns (initially empty).

From [Plotly Express Line API](https://plot.ly/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line.html#plotly.express.line):

> y (str or int or Series or array-like) – Either a name of a column in data_frame, or a pandas Series or array_like object. Values from this column or array_like are used to position marks along the y axis in cartesian coordinates...

From what I understand this means when you specify a `str` / `int` it will try to get the data from the column with that name / index, but if you specify `Series` /  `array-like` structure - it will consider that structure to be the data itself.

I hope this helps!